# Building API and integration testing artifacts in Azure Devops Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a build pipeline in Azure Devops which has the below configuration to create an artifact for the APIs. I have a separate integration testing project which I would like to publish as part of the build pipeline.

```
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: Publish and Zip Project
    inputs: 
      command: publish
      arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId)'
      modifyOutputPath: false
      zipAfterPublish: true
      publishWebProjects: false
      projects: '**/My.API.csproj'

  - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
    displayName: Publish App
    inputs:
      targetPath: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId)
      artifact: MyApi-Release
      publishLocation: pipeline
```

Can I add the below tasks to build the integration testing artifact? However is there a way to push the files for integration testing into a different directory or clean up `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId)` before it is pushed and zipped?

```
      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: Publish and Zip Integration Testing Project
    inputs: 
        command: publish
        arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId)'
        modifyOutputPath: false
        zipAfterPublish: true
        publishWebProjects: false
        projects: '**/My.API.IntegrationTests.csproj'
  
  - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
    displayName: Publish Integration Testing App
    inputs:
        targetPath: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId)
        artifact: MyApi-IntTest-Release
        publishLocation: pipeline
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes of course you can add subdirectory like `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/API/$(Build.BuildId)` and `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Integration/$(Build.BuildId)`

```
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: Publish and Zip Project
    inputs: 
      command: publish
      arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/API/$(Build.BuildId)'
      modifyOutputPath: false
      zipAfterPublish: true
      publishWebProjects: false
      projects: '**/My.API.csproj'

  - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
    displayName: Publish App
    inputs:
      targetPath: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/API/$(Build.BuildId)
      artifact: MyApi-Release
      publishLocation: pipeline
```

and

```
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: Publish and Zip Integration Testing Project
    inputs: 
        command: publish
        arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Integration/$(Build.BuildId)'
        modifyOutputPath: false
        zipAfterPublish: true
        publishWebProjects: false
        projects: '**/My.API.IntegrationTests.csproj'
  
  - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
    displayName: Publish Integration Testing App
    inputs:
        targetPath: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Integration/$(Build.BuildId)
        artifact: MyApi-IntTest-Release
        publishLocation: pipeline
```

Of course you can put this in single job.

Comment: Thanks @Krzysztof Madej. Is there a way to run a dotnet test against the published artifact "MyApi-IntTest-Release"?

Comment: Yes. Of course. Upu just need to point to dll https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test#arguments